# Can $2^s+3^s+\cdots +q^s$ , $q$ odd prime , $s\ge 2$ be a perfect power?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, summation, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

Let $q$ be an odd prime and $s\ge 2$ be an integer. Define the sum

$$S(q,s):=\sum_{p\ prime,p\le q} p^s=2^s+3^s+\cdots +q^s$$

> Can $S(q,s)$ be a perfect power ? Among other searches, I searched for $s\le 1000$ and $q\le1000$ and did not find an example.

Comment: @Ethan I did various searches. For the exponents upto $30$, I checked upto $q\le 10^7$

Comment: For exponents $2\le s\le 120$ , $q$ must be greater than $10^6$ , for $2\le s\le 10$, $q$ must be greater than $10^8$

Comment: Just to do feedback about it, but I think that my comment isn't useful and has no a good mathematical content (I'm agree that my comment is fantasy): if we assume  that we can split (case of an even number $2L$ of summands in your finite series) your expression as $L$ pairs of expressions $p^s+(\hat{p})^s=\frac{1}{L}x^y$, where also we assume that $L\mid x$, the abc conjecture implies that $\forall\epsilon>0$ does exist a constant $C(\epsilon)$ such that $\frac{1}{L}x^y\leq C(\epsilon)(p\cdot \hat{p}\cdot\frac{x}{L})^{1+\epsilon}$.

Comment: For $s=2$ and $s=3$, $q$ must be greater than $3\cdot 10^9$

Comment: In the case $s=2$ , $q$ must be greater than $11\cdot 10^9$

Comment: @Ethan Do you have any heuristic indicating that there should be an example ?